# Script to send sheet as email to address in cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this script:

`function EmailQuote() { var message = { to: "ben@xxxxxx.co.uk", subject: "Quote", body: "Hi, Please find attached quote", //name: "", attachments: [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getAs(MimeType.PDF).setName("Quote")] } MailApp.sendEmail(message); }`

to send an email of the sheet as a pdf.

I would like it to send the email to the address in cell B13 instead of to ben@xxxxxx.co.uk.

Can anyone help with how to do this please?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change  "ben@xxxxxx.co.uk" with SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("B13").getValue()

Comment: Thanks Martin, that give "Syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' line: 28 file: Code.gs" on saving, any ideas please?

Comment: Mmm, there's some extra dot or another character missing. Have you left the comma before subject?

Comment: Changing that give the error message "Syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' line: 28 file: Code.gs" I tried this before

Comment: Before the word subject? No if so

Comment: This is what I have now:

Comment: function EmailQuote() {
  var message = {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("B13").getValue()
    subject: "Quote",
    body: "Hi, Please find attached quote",
    //name: "",
    attachments: [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getAs(MimeType.PDF).setName("Quote")]
  }
  MailApp.sendEmail(message);
}

Comment: Effectively you're missing a comma after getValue() ;) add it so you can read "...getValue(), subject...."

Comment: Still the same with the comma

Comment: function EmailQuote() {
  var message = {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("B13").getValue(),
    subject: "Quote",
    body: "Hi, Please find attached quote",
       attachments: [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getAs(MimeType.PDF).setName("Quote")]
  }
  MailApp.sendEmail(message);
}

Comment: Try this function EmailQuote() {
  var email = SpreadsheetApp.gretActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("B13").getValue()
   var message = { email, subject: "Quote", body: "Hi, Please find attached quote", attachments: [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getAs(MimeType.PDF).setName("Quote")] } MailApp.sendEmail(message); }

Comment: Just the same :(

Comment: You unintentionally erased "to: " the first time: function EmailQuote() {
  var email = SpreadsheetApp.gretActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("B13").getValue()
   var message = { to: email, subject: "Quote", body: "Hi, Please find attached quote", attachments: [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getAs(MimeType.PDF).setName("Quote")] }
  MailApp.sendEmail(message); }

Comment: There was a miss type, now get "Failed to send email: no recipient"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249532/discussion-between-martin-and-ben-c).

Comment: Corrected that, IT WORKS!  Many Thanks For your time and effort Martin

Comment: Great! I'm glad